# "I never worked on Saturdays" vs "I never used to work on Saturdays"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between

> I never used to work on Saturdays.

and

> I never worked on Saturdays.

Comment: In an appropriate context, they may well have the same meaning. Your first example may simply be a denial of the positive "You used to work on Saturdays", (didn't you?).

Answer (score 2):

> I never worked on Saturdays.

This sentence just says that you did not work on Saturdays, and that's it.

> I never used to work on Saturdays.

This sentence implies that you did not work on Saturdays before, **but do now**.  This phrasing ("I used to") usually is followed up with a "but..." or "however...".  Even though it is not explicitly written, the meaning is different.  For example, the fuller sentence could be:

> I never used to work on Saturdays, **but** I do now.

Answer (score 0):

We use *used to* to talk about habits in the past we don't do anymore. Conversely, the negative form *didn't use to* or *never used to* (a bit stronger) means you didn't have mentioned habits until now.

The second sentence doesn't carry this implication.